# Concatenating Column Names in a Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

New situation to me. I have need to pivot the concatenation results of 2 columns from a table.  For example, I have the following able to be pivoted:

```
CREATE TABLE #pivSource(
ID INT,
Name VARCHAR(50),
Acronym VARCHAR(20),
[Type] VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #pivSource(ID, Name, Acronym, [Type])
SELECT 1, 'Emily','ABC',  'A'
UNION 
SELECT 2, 'Lorenzo','DEF',  'B' 
UNION
SELECT 3, 'Estelle','GHI',  'C'
UNION
SELECT 4, 'Rosie','JKL',  'D'
UNION
SELECT 5, 'Paula','MNO',  'E'
UNION
SELECT 6, 'Rick', 'PQR',  'F'
UNION
SELECT 7, 'Elvira','STU',  'G'
UNION
SELECT 8, 'Eva','VWX',  'H'
UNION
SELECT 9, 'Erick','YZ0',  'I'

SELECT * FROM #pivSource
```

Gives you the following result set:

```
ID  Name    Acronym Type
1   Emily   ABC A
2   Lorenzo DEF B
3   Estelle GHI C
4   Rosie   JKL D
5   Paula   MNO E
6   Rick    PQR F
7   Elvira  STU G
8   Eva VWX H
9   Erick   YZ0 I
```

I want to concatenate columns in a pivot which would give a result set like this:

```
ID  ABCA  DEFB   GHIC   JKLD   MNLE   PQRF   STUG   VWXH   YZ0I
1   1     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2   0     1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0        
3   0     0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0    
4   0     0      0      1      0      0  0      0      0
5   0     0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0    
6   0     0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0    
7   0     0      0      0      0      0      1      0      0    
8   0     0      0      0      0      0      0      1      0    
9   0     0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1
```

In essence I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    #pivSource
PIVOT 
    (COUNT(Name)  
    FOR Acronym + [Type] IN(
        [ABC] + [A],
        [DEF] + [B],
        [GHI] + [C],
        [JKL] + [D],
        [MNO] + [E],
        [PQR] + [F],
        [STU] + [G],
        [VWX] + [H],
        [YZ0] + [I])
) AS PivAcrnmType ORDER BY ID;
```

This isn't working however, nor is separating with commas (i.e. `...FOR Acronym , [Type] IN(...`.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subquery or CTE to concatenate and then PIVOT:

**[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ac1e1/3/0)**

```
;WITH cte
AS
(
  SELECT
      Id,
      Name,
      AcronymType =  Acronym + Type
  FROM pivSource
)
SELECT * 
FROM  cte
PIVOT 
(
    COUNT(Name)  
    FOR AcronymType IN(
        [ABCA],
        [DEFB],
        [GHIC],
        [JKLD],
        [MNOE],
        [PQRF],
        [STUG],
        [VWXH],
        [YZ0I])
) AS PivAcrnmType
 ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think about that; rookie mistake perhaps.  Thanks.  Will accept when time limit is up.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried concatenating before pivoting?

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    (select *, Acronym + [Type] as acronym_type
     from #pivSource) p
PIVOT 
    (COUNT(Name)  
    FOR acronym_type IN(
        'ABCA',
        'DEFB',
        'GHIC',
        'JKLD',
        'MNOE',
        'PQRF',
        'STUG',
        'VWXH',
        'YZ0I')
) AS PivAcrnmType ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think about that; rookie mistake perhaps.  Thanks.